# How to wait for tomcat server to start up in Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

It may be a weird question and I have tried searching but couldn't find what I am looking for.
I have a below playbook which starts tomcat and checks the status. How do i put a condition to wait for it to become online before my playbook finishes. I have looked into wait_for module but not able to put up in the playbook.

```
---
 - name: Starting tomcat service on remote host
   shell: "svcadm enable tomcat"
   ignore_errors: true

 - pause:
     seconds: 10

 - name: Check the State of tomcat service on the remote host
   shell: "svcs tomcat"
   register: tomcat_status

 - set_fact:
     tomcat_state: "{{ tomcat_status.stdout_lines.1.split().0 }}"
```

The value of **tomcat_state** should be "online" which tells us that tomcat is up.

Is there anything we can do here OR may be some other way? Appreciate if someone can give some inputs

Answer (score 1):

```
- name: wait for completion
  wait_for:
      port: <your_port>
      delay: 60
      timeout: 500
```

In this way, this task wait for 60 secs, then check if something is up on the port you specified, and it tries for 500s

Comment: Note that there are potential problems using `wait_for` like this: just because the port is open doesn't mean that the tomcat application is actually ready to service requests. If you're trying to access the service immediately after this task, you may instead want to use the `uri` module in  an [until loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#retrying-a-task-until-a-condition-is-met).

Comment: @larsks I tried it actually but i get the below error. My remote servers can't be accessed from outside nor they have internet connectivity.
```server1 failed | msg: Failed to connect to mytest.com at port 443: [Errno 146] Connection refused
``` SoI am not sure if the uri module would work

Comment: why do you want access your server form external? set remote_src to yes to execute the task on your node. By the way, I used wait_for because he asked about it